# How to compare const char* with a string in C++?

Tags: c++, string, comparison

I am working with C++ and I am trying to compare strings.

Below is my code which gives me back `const char*` -

```
    const char* client_id() const {
        return String(m_clientPos);
    }
```

And now I am comparing the strings like this -

```
cout<<client_ptr->client_id()<< endl;
if (strcmp(client_ptr->client_id(), "Hello")) {
    ..
} else {
    ..
}
```

but it never goes into if statement. But my cout prints out `Hello` correctly. Is there anything wrong I am doing?

Comment: where it prints "hello"?

Comment: why you converting `m_clientIdPos` to `string` if the return type is `const char*`?

Comment: I meant where is the print statement?

Comment: That's not my code base. Somebody else wrote it like that. Is there any problem with that?

Comment: Just above the if block I have a cout.

Comment: there is obvious problem, `String` is not built in type, (did u mean `string`?). if there is a user defined `String` type, then the code will not compile

Comment: the condition should be `if (! strcmp(client_ptr->client_id(), "Hello")) `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do `if (0 == strcmp(...`

See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/

> `strcmp`
>
> Returns an integral value indicating the relationship between the strings:
> A zero value indicates that both strings are equal.
> A value greater than zero indicates that the first character that does not match has a greater value in str1 than in str2; And a value less than zero indicates the opposite.

Answer (score 2):

> it never goes into if statement.

The `strcmp` function returns zero when the strings are the same, so you should see the code hit the `else` branch when the two strings are equal to each other.

- A zero value indicates that both strings are equal.
- A value greater than zero indicates that the first character that does not match has a greater value in str1 than in str2;
- And a value less than zero indicates the opposite.

Since `String` does not look like a built-in class and assuming that you have access to its source, you may be better off making the comparison with `const char*` a member function of the `String` class.